# Trac stopped working after Ubuntu upgrdade from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: trac

I ran an upgrade of my Ubuntu machine from 12.04 to 14.04 and afterwards, I noticed that my Trac stopped working, giving me this error message on the webpage:

```
"AttributeError: Cannot find an implementation of the "IRequestHandler" interface named "WikiModule".  Please update the option trac.default_handler in trac.ini."
```

I googled around a lot to see if others experienced this problem, but found no solution. Did anyone encounter and solve this?

Comment: Try removing `default_handler = TagsWikiModule` from your trac.ini file.

Comment: I don't have that in the file.

Comment: I fixed it by reinstalling the entire server from scratch. I think what broke wasn't Trac, but my Apache2 configuration files during the update. I couldn't tell what got broken.